# Finding a matrix U such that B=UA.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 & 1 \\
2 &  3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}B=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  3 & 0 \\
4 &  3 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}

How does one go about solving this problem?

Find the matrix U such that B=UA and express U as a product of elementary matrices.

Basically, I tried solving the problem using trial and error trying to go from A to B and applying those elementary row operation to the identity matrix to make U. However, this method is still not efficient enough in my head.

So, is there a faster method? (Even by trial and error, I could not find the matrix. I am not good with trial and error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: (the first two columns of $B$) is $U$ times (the first two columns of $A$).
If the first two columns of $A$ formed the identity matrix, $U$ would just be the first two columns of $B$.  It isn't, but you can take some row operations...

EDIT: In row reduction of $A$, the first step might be subtracting $2$ times row $1$ from row $2$.  This is accomplished by the matrix multiplication $E_1 A$, where $E_1$ is the elementary matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 0\cr -2 & 1\cr}$.
One more row operation, corresponding to an elementary matrix $E_2$, gives you 
a matrix whose first two columns are the identity, i.e. 
$$E_2 E_1 A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & *\cr 0 & 1 & *\cr}$$
(where I'm not specifying what the $*$ entries are).
Similarly, there are elementary matrices $E_3$, $E_4$ such that the first two
columns of $E_3 E_4 B$ form the identity matrix.  If it happens that
$E_3 E_4 B = E_1 E_2 A$ (which is something you should check!), then
$B = E_4^{-1} E_3^{-1} E_1 E_2 A$, so you can take $U = E_4^{-1} E_3^{-1} E_1 E_2$ (note that the inverse of an elementary matrix is an elementary matrix).

Comment: Robert, do you mean U as a matrix or as a scalar multiple?

Comment: Hmm... I am kind of lost. Can you provide visual explanatin

Comment: Thanks Robert. That was very clear.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: Firstly observe that since $A,B$ have dimension $2\times 3$ then $U$ has dimension $2\times2$. Thus $$U=\begin{pmatrix}u_1 &u_2 \\ u_3 & u_4\end{pmatrix}$$ Multiplying U with A and setting equal to B gives you the set of equations $$\begin{cases}u_1+2u_2=1 \\0u_1+3u_2=3\\u_1+u_2=0\end{cases}$$ and similarly for $u_3,u_4$. The result is $$U=\begin{pmatrix}-1 &1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
For the second part: An elementary matrix is a matrix that differs from the identity matrix by one single elementary row operation. For this I do not see another way (to the moment) than trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

We want to perform row operations on $A$ in order to transform it into $B$. By inspection, notice that we can do this by:

- Adding ($2$ times row $1$) to row $2$ to get:
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 &  0 & 1 \\
  4 &  3 & 3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
- Scaling (row $1$) by $3$ to get:
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  3 & 0 & 3 \\
  4 & 3 & 3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
- Adding ($-1$ times row $2$) to row $1$ to get:
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & -3 & 0 \\
  4 & 3 & 3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
- Scaling (row $1$) by $-1$ to get:
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 3 & 0 \\
  4 & 3 & 3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$

It remains to translate each row operation to an elementary matrix and multiply them together.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $A^T$ the matrix transpose of $A$ and $C^{-1}$ the matrix inverse of square matrix $C$. Then we have:

$$UA=B\implies U(A.A^T)=B.A^T\implies U=B.A^T (A.A^T)^{-1}$$

$$\implies U=\begin{pmatrix}-1 &1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Ingenious method of avoiding the 2x3 problem. However, one things that irks me is that the inverse of A does not exist since it is not square. I think you should correct that.

Comment: $C=A.A^T$ is a 2x2 matrix and I am only inverting $C$.